# How do I use a DLL in ASP.NET Web Forms environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

Currently, I'm trying to use a DLL in a Web Forms ASP.NET environment. This DLL is used to control a hardware using a UDP connection. My problem is: the first time I use the command, it seems work. If I click on the button again, it shows the error "Could not bind the socket. The address and port is already in use".

I already did some applications using Windows Forms and everything worked fine. I can use the command many times and not get this problem. Below, the code I'm using to do this:

```
using MyDLL;

string teste;
int result;
CommandClient UDPcmd = new CommandClient();
result = UDPcmd.PulseDoor("192.168.1.100", 2003, 0, out teste);
Resultado.Text = teste;
```

Any help? The problem only happens in web platform. Windows Forms work properly.

Comment: Is the DLL written in managed code (C#, VB.NET F# etc) or is it unmanaged code?

Comment: Do you need to close the connection after use so it can be used again next time? UDPcmd.Close();

Comment: unfortunatelly, it's a unmanaged code. I'm using a dll done by another person. I guess it was wrote using VB.

Comment: Steve, using windows forms i don't need to close it. The DLL don't have this method as well. =/ thank you for your help!!

Comment: If the DLL was written in VB.NET, then it's managed code.

Comment: Sorry Mason, i'm just new on it. DLL already compiled. When i said unmanaged, i would like to say (i cannot edit the methods, because i dont have the source code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend help me and give me the command below. It worked properly.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(UDPcmd);
```

Thank you everybody for your help!!
Regards.